# Why my integration test waits for async Promise in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm using `async.map` to merge fetch data from db using ids. Also, I save the result into redis for caching also, but it looks like my mocha test waits for the Promise to finish even I didn't call `then` because I thought it would just fire and forget. Am I missing something?

Here's the code.

```
    queries.query(druidQuery)
    .then(addDetails)
    .catch(function catchFunc(err) {
      return reply(Boom.badImplementation(err, {message: err}));
    });

    function addDetails(response) {
      async.map(response, addDetailsList, function mapFunc(err, output) {
        return reply({
          data: output,
          query: options
        });
      });
    }

    function addDetailsList(items, cb) {
      async.map(items.result, addDetailsItem, cb);
    }

    function addDetailsItem(item, cb) {
      crawler.crawl(item).then(function(results) {
        crawler.set(item, JSON.stringify(results));
        var crawlOut = _.extend(item, results);
        return cb(null, crawlOut);
      }).catch(function() {
        return cb(null, item);
      });
    }
```

My test wouldn't exit as long as I have this line.

`crawler.set(item, JSON.stringify(results));`

And this is the code of that line.

```
var sh = require('shorthash');
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var redis = require('redis');

var config = require('../config');

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

    set: function set(url, contents) {
        var redisClient = redis.createClient({
          host: config.redis.url,
          port: config.redis.port
        });

        var urlHash = sh.unique(url);
        return redisClient.setAsync(urlHash, contents);
      },
```

If I take this line out `crawler.set(item, JSON.stringify(results));` my test would exit after it's finished.

Update

```
describe('/', function postsDesc() {
    after(function after(done) {
      server.stop({timeout: 5000}, function err(errorResponse) {
        if(errorResponse) {
          throw errorResponse;
        }
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should get analytics posts with from date', function it(done) {
      var url = '/';

      server.inject(url, function injectResponse(response) {
        expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        done();
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: could you post your test delcaration including `it` statement, and could you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. It's just stuck there. I'll post the desc and it